# Deep links does not work from emails

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome

Some mail services such as mail.ru, mail.yandex.ru and I guess many others add to link parameter `rel="noopener"`, so that looks like this

```
<a href="http://mylink.com/path/to/my.jsp" rel="noopener">
```

So if I have intent filter in my android app

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https"/>
        <data android:scheme="http"/>
        <data android:host="www.mylink.com"/>
        <data android:pathPrefix="/path/to/my.jsp"/>
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="myapp"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Deep links does not work on Google Chrome. But without `rel="noopener"` it works like a charm.
I tried to make redirect from js frontend with something like

```
window.location = "intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=myapp;package=com.app.myapp;end";
```

And that works only without `rel="noopener"`.

I have no idea how to fix it, **is it possible?**

UPD:

1. Deep link in window.location with "myapp://" does not work too
2. Services like http://appredirect.com/ doesnt work too
3. Impossible to add some js to email which will remove
   `rel="noopener"`
4. Multiple href parameters in link with one of "myapp://" doesnt work